# Matplotlib type error when saving multiple plots into a single pdf file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

After going through hours of frustration I decided to ask this question hoping somebody might have encountered the same issue. Basically, **I'm trying to save multiple plots into a pdf file** but getting the following Type error:

```
TypeError: Don't know a PDF representation for <class 'numpy.ndarray'> objects.
```

I'm looping through a big dataset defining each column as a dictionary key and plotting each series. My code is quite complex, so giving a simple example here. But note if i test PdfPages with a simple example it works just fine producing a pdf file with multiple pages.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

list2 = []
pdf = PdfPages("foo.pdf")
for i in list1:
    for cnt, elem in enumerate(dict1['key1']):
        if elem == i:
            list2.append(dict1['key1'][cnt])
    fig = plt.figure()

    for b in list2:
        y_l = l_dict[b]
        y_m = m_dict[b]

        plt.plot_date(x_l_date, y_l)
        plt.scatter(x_m_date, y_m)
    ax = plt.gca()
    plt.grid()
    pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
plt.show()
```

I do not have any error in my code if I don't use `savefig`, so no error in the numpy arrays etc.

Comment: Nothing is mixed up. List1 just contains a list of item names.

Comment: Could you please give a working example? We can not test it as it is.